# Create get_full_name in django on from foreign model

Tags: django

I have two model called User and Userprofile like below. I want to render display user full_name associated with its own post in django templates. Currently It is only displaying user email instead of user full name in the templates.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', ]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
```

And another model is here

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_("Middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=50)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("User profiles")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.middle_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([name for name in [
            self.first_name,
            self.middle_name,
            self.last_name
        ] if name])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userprofile_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

How can I render user full_name instead of user email or username in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in template the concrete user, you may do it like that:

```
<p>{{ user.userprofile.get_full_name }}</p>
```

see more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#variables

If you want return user first_name if method User.get_full_name you may do it like that:

```
def get_full_name(self):
    return self.userprofile.first_name
```

Comment: I'm looking something like rendering author name in the post.  I'm using this code ```{{post.auther.get_full_name}}``` I know it display user email becoz i'm returning user email in the model but I want to return user first_name in the User model.

Answer (score 1):

try this

in models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_("Middle name"), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=50)

  .......
  @property
  def get_full_name(self):
    if self.first_name or self.last_name:
        return ("%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)).strip()
    return self.user.email
```

in template

```
{{ user.userprofile.get_full_name }}
```

Comment: I've another model called Post 
```class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name=_(
        "Author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()  
    published = PostPublishedManager()  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", kwargs={
            "pk": self.pk
        })
```
Now I want to render author name instead of email because it automatically save user email. Am I missing some thing?.